# Android/HTML: Pass JSONArray as return type to JS in HTML

Tags: android, html, json

I have a HTML page which is viewed in a webview. In this, there is a JS that calls an Android function (written in the Web Interface).

the function returns JSONArray

```
public JSONArray getresults(){
                  .
                  .
    return resultSet; 
}
```

I had the debugger point at resultSet and it showed the JSONArray perfectly.

I am receiving this JSONArray in the HTML through:

```
var data = Android.getresults();
```

And here the value of data is not complete. I understand, there is something I am missing. Please can you help?

UPDATE:

I am using this data in the HTML page to create a list dynamically:

```
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + '<img src="' + val.FilePath +'" alt="" />' + val.Comment +  '</li>');
    });
    $('<ul/>', {        
        html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('body');
    });
```

Unfortunately, this doesnt work. And if I hard code the data variable to

```
 data = [{"Comment":"check it","FilePath":"\/storage\/sdcard0\/test\/20130914154816.JPEG"}];
```

it works like charm.. Whats the difference?

Comment: What do you mean by "not complete"?

Comment: "this doesnt work" is a useless description of your symptoms. When you inspected `data`, what does it hold after the call to `Android.getresults();`?